# Project MyAzureFunc is not compatible with netstandard2.0 > (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-standard

I have an Azure Function App project in Visual Studio in .NET Core 2.2 which I would like to unit test. Therefore, I added a second project (Class Library) with some unit tests.
However, I get the following compilation error:

> Project MyAzureFunc is not compatible with netstandard2.0
>   (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Project MyAzureFunc supports:
>   netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2)

For the Class Library / Unit tests I can only choose between .NET Standard (1.0 .. 2.0), not for .NET Core itself.

Should I download an additional SDK for .NET Core to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a .NET Core Unit Test project. In Visual Studio 2019, follow these steps to do so:

- On the startup screen, select *Create new project*
- In the search box, type *test*
- Select the desired project type: *MSTest, xUnit or NUnit Test Project (.NET Core)*
- Click *Next* to continue creating the project
- Implement the desired unit tests

[image: Create a new Unit Test project]